# SIGABRT on sprintf

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, segmentation-fault, printf

My code keep crashing (it's an old iOS app, *without ARC*). This is the code in question:

```
- (NSString *) dataToHex:(NSData *)data {
    NSUInteger len2 = [data length] * 2;
    unsigned char* chars = (unsigned char*) [data bytes];

    char finalChar[len2 + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
        sprintf(finalChar + (i * 2), "%02x", chars[i]);
    }

    finalChar[len2] = '\0';

    NSString *hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", finalChar];

    return hexString;
}
```

The crash is in the line of `sprintf()`. Any ideas? I've tried using bigger buffer sizes, but doesn't work.

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes, it's filled with the bytes of the NSData passed as parameter, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
```

should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

(otherwise you're reading beyond the end of your input data and writing beyond the end of your output data).

Answer (score 3):

In your case, the size of the `finalChar` array is `len2 + 1`. later, in the `for` loop, by saying

```
for(int i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
        sprintf(finalChar + (i * 2), "%02x", chars[i]);
    }
```

`finalChar + (i * 2)` will point to out of bound memory at some point (when `i` will be greater than `len2/2`) because, `i` is not limited to `data length`. Out of bound memory access cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

I believe, it should be something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < len2/2 ; i++) {
        sprintf(finalChar + (i * 2), "%02x", chars[i]);
    }
```